# file upload in Django not saving file anywhere

Tags: django, django-forms

I am really lost and I hope you guys can help me. I am trying to do a simple file upload form on Django. The form shows on screen and submitting it doesn't throw an error, but the file is not saved anywhere.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks a lot

**VIEWS.PY**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import UploadFileForm
from .functions import handle_uploaded_file

def upload_file(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['file'])
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/success/url/')
    else:
        form = UploadFileForm()
    return render(request, 'enter.html', {'form': UploadFileForm})
```

**FORMS.PY**

```
from django import forms

class UploadFileForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    file = forms.FileField()
```

**FUNCTIONS.PY**

```
def handle_uploaded_file(f):
    with open('rrls/media/upload/name.txt', 'wb+') as destination:
        for chunk in f.chunks():
            destination.write(chunk)
```

Answer (score 0):

have you used enctype in form tag

```
<form method="POST" class="post-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```